# How to move the content of a textbox into another textbox using AngularJs on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a text-box with a certain content entered into that,how will i work on to move the content of that text box into an another text box on click of a button........by emptying the previous text box completely.

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
                <p>Invite People</p>
                <div class="invite-user-text">
                    <!-- <input type="text" class="invite-user-input" autocomplete="off"
                        data-keyboard-layer="invite-user-text" placeholder=""> -->


                    <tags-input ng-model="tags" display-property="name"
                        placeholder="Add User" replace-spaces-with-dashes="false">
                    <auto-complete source="loadCountries($query)" min-length="0"
                        load-on-focus="true" load-on-empty="true"
                        max-results-to-show="32" template="my-custom-template"></auto-complete>
                    </tags-input>

                    <script type="text/ng-template" id="my-custom-template">

  <div class="right-panel">
    <span ng-bind-html="$highlight($getDisplayText())"></span>
    <span>{{data.email}}</span>
  </div>
</script>
```

I have the above Html code and a js to that to display the contents has tags by using ng-input-tag library in a text box.....i want to move that content(tags) to the another text box using angular js on click of the button

```
<button type="button" ng-click=""
                    class="btn btn-md pull-right add-user-btn" ng-disabled="">
                    Add Users</button>
            </div>

            </button>
            <div class="col-sm-7 user-text-area">
                <p>Deal Administrator</p>
            </div>
```

Comment: In HTML there is no "text-box" element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap this also in a function in your controller:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="text=tags">
```

And then your text input:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="text">
```

This will give you the tags json in your text input.

**Edit:**
You can have a look at this complete plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/1db1Af?p=preview

And this is how you can get the values of the tags:

```
$scope.moveTagsToTextInput = function(){
$scope.text = "";
angular.forEach($scope.tags, function(value, key) {
  $scope.text += value.text + " ";
});
$scope.tags = "";
}
```

Comment: Thank you!...yes but still i can't see the logic to move the content....can you please explain?@Ozlet

Comment: Have a look at the plunkr I added.

Comment: Thank you...:)........but i can see only the text inside  a tag is moving,Can we move the whole tag with custom styling and the same functions as it possess in the previous text box...?@Ozlet

Comment: No you can't have custom styling inside a text input. You can use a second tags-input field if you want to still have the tags as they were.

Comment: Thank you..:)@Olezt